# Shouldn't the definition of closure be more stringent?

Tags: closures

I believe I detect ambiguity in the definition of a closure.  Specifically it seems as though it would allow the outer scope to be the global scope.

For instance from the wikipedia article at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

"A closure (also lexical closure, function closure or function value) is a function together with a referencing environment for the non-local variables of that function."

Specifically non-local could include global variables.  Even the article on non local variables at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_variable states that "the term can refer to global variables".  It does go on to qualify matters by stating that globals are not what is usually meant.

Nevertheless, I think we might need to be more stringent in the definition of closures to specifically exclude global variables as the non-local variables.  Or is there some case where globals are valid in this context?

EDIT:

Based on comments received and additional thought, to me it seems that there is one specific circumstance where the current definition of closure, ignoring globals, falls short.  And that is when the code/function that might otherwise qualify as a closure, can *only* reference non-local variables that are also global variables

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're implying that a closure cannot reference global variables. This is not true.

Comment: Formally, a closure includes globals, but since you have access to globals even without a closure, there is no extra work necessary, so people tend to ignore them when discussing closure-related issues.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes that's what I'm trying to discern: whether or not it's acceptable or not to reference global variables from a closure.  Or perhaps more precisely, if the only possible outer scope is the global scope, is what you're creating really a closure, or just a function that has access to globals?  Something like that -- guess my own question isn't precise enough?

Comment: You're creating a closure that has no special powers beyond those of non-closure functions, so most compilers optimize it into a non-closure function. Asking whether it's "really" a closure is like asking "I bought a sports car, but I never drive it fast, and I only use it to go to the grocery store. Is it really a sports car?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, yes, see comments above.  It may not matter to application developers, but it should matter to compiler/interpreter developers.  No sense optimizing something away if you can recognize it in the first place.